# Node.js , Express ejs views error

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

EJS Error: Failed to lookup view "admin_landing2" in views directory "/Users/aryanarora/Desktop/asn3/views".
while trying make a call to localhost/8080/yolo
I am getting the same error even if I switch to hbs. (i have installed both the packages)

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
var fs = require('fs');
// const hbs = require('hbs');
// hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + './views'); 

// app.set('view engine','hbs');


// Require static assets from public folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Set 'views' directory for any views 
// being rendered res.render()
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// Set view engine as EJS
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


var users = [];

//app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.use('/', function(req,res,next){
  console.log(req.method, 'request:', req.url);

  next();
});


app.locals.yolo = require('./Data/courses.json');

//Request i am trying to get//

app.get('/yolo',function(req,res){
  //res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/admin_landing2.hbs'));
  res.render('admin_landing2', {var1 : "pehla" , var2 : "dusra"});
});

app.get('/login', function(req,res){

  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/admin_login.html'));
  var filepath = './admin_login.html';
  console.log(filepath);
});
```

Comment: It can't find the view file in `/Users/aryanarora/Desktop/asn3/views`. Check the file name, location, etc.

Comment: the asn3 folder has all the files (HTML, js and server files) the file I am trying to render is admin_landing2 is correct too. i even made the admin_landing2.ejs with extension (.ejs). still doesn't work

Comment: does it have the `views` directory inside it and the `admin_landing2.ejs` is in the `views` directory?

Comment: no such directory. only one file in the main folder admin_landing2.ejs (that too the one i saved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the `views` directory to the wrong location.

**Do**

```
app.set('views', __dirname)
```

**instead of**

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
```

Comment: Dude thank you so much, I have been stuck on this for so long.